# PHP and Rails for NginX configuration

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, nginx, url-rewriting, passenger

I have both PHP and Rails running on the same server.
I used to have a rewrite rule at nginx.conf

```
location / {
    index index.php; 
}
```

and in case of URL like `/foo/bar` `/foo/bar/index.php` was served.

But now I have also Rails (Passenger) and with this rule I can't hit rails.
How do I check if there exist index.php before and hit rails only if it does not.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should `try_files`

```
server {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $uri/index.php @passenger;

        location @passenger {
                passenger_enabled on;
                rails_env development;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood Your question, You will need to define another location block, that "hits" rails and use try_files in current one. Something like this.

```
index index.html index.php # better place this outside location block

upstream thin {
    unix:/tmp/thin.0.socket;  # this could be any other rails server socket
    unix:/tmp/thin.1.socket;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri @rails;
}

location @rails {
    proxy_pass http://thin;
}
```

These would be essential parts for such configuration, of course it lacks proxy configuration.
[a more detailed example for similar application](http://wiki.nginx.org/RubyonRailsMongrel)

Comment: What is unix:/tmp/thin.0.socket;? Should it be a passenger's socket?

Comment: It should be socket of whichever application serves Your rails. Thin is just one such example.